# Validation rule not displaying error message

Tags: validation-rule, sales-cloud

I have an Opportunity which has Type = ZMS - Budget Increase and Offerings = ZMS. If those conditions are met, then I won't be able to modify couple of fields -> offerings cannot be modified either.

When I change value for the other fields I receive error message, but when changing the Offerings to something else I don't receive an error message even though I should.

Am I missing something? Offerings it's a multi-select picklist field

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Offerings__c, "ZMS"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type, "ZMS - Budget Increase"),
    OR(
     ISCHANGED(AccountId),
     ISCHANGED(Offerings__c),
     ISCHANGED(ParentOpportunity__c),
     ISCHANGED(LeadSource__c),
     ISCHANGED(CampaignId),
    )
)
```

Comment: As a general note: Validation rules are not a great tool for things like "only allow fields X, Y, and Z to be changed" because users can change _any_ restricted field _so long as at least one of the "allowed" fields are changing at the same time_. You could work around that by adding `ISCHANGED()` for _every_ field on your SObject, but that's not really practical. The more appropriate solution here is to use a Flow or Trigger to change the RecordType of the record, and assign a page layout to it (where you're able to mark fields as "read-only", only enforced for people using the UI).

Comment: I agree with you Derek, validation rule it's not really the perfect answer for this scenario. The architect in the team decided to go with this solution, it wasn't my decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the `Offerings__c` field to something that doesn't include "ZMS" then your validation rule doesn't run, because you are first checking `INCLUDES(Offerings__c, "ZMS")`.

To check that no one changes the Offerings field from ZMS you can use the [`PRIORVALUE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_priorvalue.htm&type=5) function.

Comment: I replaced  INCLUDES(Offerings__c, "ZMS") with  INCLUDES(PRIORVALUE(ZalandoOfferings__c),"ZMS") and it's working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably you need both? E.g.: `OR(INCLUDES(Offerings__c, "ZMS"), INCLUDES(PRIORVALUE(ZalandoOfferings__c),"ZMS"))`

Comment: Do you think it's not enough to have only  INCLUDES(PRIORVALUE(ZalandoOfferings__c),"ZMS")? if I have only this, when opp has Offerings = ZMS and Type = ZMS Budget Increase and I want to change some field mentioned in the validation rule, I receive error so that's good. And when I have opp with Offerings = ZMS and Type = TypeTest and I try to modify some field included in the validation rule, I will not receive error. I am trying to understand why you think I should put both.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. I assumed you wanted to prevent any of the listed fields changing when the Offerings field is ZMS. If you just do `PRIORVALUE` then it will only prevent the fields changing if the original value of the Offerings field is ZMS, not the current one